# Would a massive graviton emit more massive gravitons?

Tags: gravity, mass, quantum-gravity

In the theory of [massive gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_gravity), suppose that two bodies start interacting by exchanging gravitons. Wouldn't these gravitons, having mass, have to exchange gravitons between themselves, with these new gravitons having to exchange more gravitons, thereby leading to infinite recursion?

I understand the range argument for massless gravitons, as explained [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/241516), but I don't understand if gravitons have mass how this seeming paradox related to infinite recursion is resolved conceptually?

Comment: The same problem is encountered in QCD - color-charged objects interact by exchanging gluons, which themselves have color charge and can themselves exchange gluons, and so and so on. The thing that saves QCD at high energies is that the coupling constant is weak (i.e. it's $\ll 1$), and so interactions with more gluon loops get less important (because each loop adds an extra factor of the coupling). So what's the coupling strength associated with a graviton loop?

Answer (score 0):

In the link you provide, the limit for the mass of the graviton is, after the discovery of the gravitational waves by LIGO as

g < $7.7×10^{−23}$ eV/c2

Such a tiny mass, together with the tiny coupling constant [associated with gravity](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html), compared to 1 for the strong interaction , 1/137 for electromagnetism, $ 6x10^{-39}$  for gravity

would ensure that what you fear in calculation would be infinitessimally small.

> Wouldn't these gravitons, having mass, have to exchange gravitons between themselves, with these new gravitons having to exchange more massive gravitons, thereby leading to infinite recursion

These gravitons have a fixed mass, as far as I can tell, there are no "more massive gravitons".

By the time a graviton would exchange a graviton with a graviton, it will have flown off to infinity, or been absorbed by some massive body. Such a small mass is practically zero.

The answer to the title question :

> Would a massive graviton emit more massive gravitons?

A graviton need not have mass to  emit gravitons, because it is a general relativity object which is described by an energy momentum vector which is affected by the space time tensor, [as the answer here discusses.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293873/do-gravitons-interact-with-each-other)

It is the couplings that are so tiny that the mathematical analogy with the strong force  cannot generate similar effects within observable times and spaces in our universe.

Comment: "more massive gravitons" was a typo, meant to say "more gravitons with mass".

Comment: So the problem is ignored because the calculations are infinitesimally small? Is this typically done in physics? Don't these gravitons have to exchange gravitons between themselves, no matter how small the mass, for this concept of mass to have meaning in this theory?

Comment: If the calculations to have a measurable effect lead to times much larger than the time of the universe? And yes, models in physics are about fitting data within measurable data prediction times and space accuracies .  It is the "infinite recursion" that is pushed to unobservable levels .