# "Speed" of gravity?

Tags: gravity, speed, causality

This is probably going to be a poorly written question, since I know really a little of physics.
Imagine a object of small mass, let's say a book, is floating in the universe in absence of any gravitational force pulling it. Now, let's say a massive object suddenly appears several light-minutes far and its gravity begins pulling the book towards it.
My question is, how long before gravitational pull starts taking effect? Does the book move immediately as the object appears, or it takes some time before gravity "reaches" it?
Also, if the pull is immediate, doesn't it mean an entity faster than light exists in the universe?

Comment: There is a limit to speed of anything in this universe. Some things move at that maximum speed, such as light and electromagnetic radiation in general. And also gravitational wave propagation. That maximum speed limit has been named the "speed of light".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the status of existing measurements of the speed of gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39260/)

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7041/

Comment: Changes in gravity propagate at c.