# The velocity of gravitational waves or the velocity of the effect of gravity

Tags: gravity, experimental-physics, speed-of-light, gravitational-waves

If the sun disappears from the solar system, the earth will remain revolving for 8 minutes and will not be freed from the sun's gravity until after 8 minutes because the speed of the effect of gravity is the speed of light Is there evidence for that Have they already tested that the speed of gravity is the speed of light in some way

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5456/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39260/2451

Comment: See [this](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/page/press-release-gw170817)